# Python TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Tags: python, typeerror

I am replacing all the occurrences of 2010 in my JSON file with a random number between 1990 and 2020.

```
import fileinput
from random import randint
f = fileinput.FileInput('data.json', inplace=True, backup='.bak')
for line in f:
    print(line.replace('2010', randint(1990, 2020)).rstrip())
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "replace.py", line 5, in
>   
>       print(line.replace('2010', randint(1990, 2020)).rstrip()) TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

And here is one example of such an occurrence:

```
"myDate" : "2010_02",
```

Comment: Is there some blank line in your json file?

Comment: @ettanany no black line! every line has at least one character.

Comment: @Mpondomise try with my solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
>
> Return a copy of string s
> with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional
> argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are
> replaced.

The new value must be string, but you are passing a value of type int.

change :

```
line.replace('2010', randint(1990, 2020)).rstrip())
```

to:

```
line.replace('2010', str(randint(1990, 2020))).rstrip()
```